# Meteor app linking to external pages/apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, flash, meteor

Hi guys I'm looking to build an application that is a list of stores. One requirement is that for each store there is a special view of the store built in flash or javascript. This special view portion has been already built by someone else. It consists of a single HTML index file and a bunch of javascript/css in it.

So I think it would be very difficult to directly it as a part of the meteor app. What I want to do is to somehow have those special view portions be a separate entity from my meteor listing app. How can this be done? Will it need to be on different servers? Or can I just have two folders (one a meteor app folder, the other just those html+css+javascript/flash files) and have the meteor app have links point to the other folder? Any examples of meteor apps pointing to separate files but still function like a single webpage?

Comment: I think it would be easier to migrate all html pages to meteor. But, maybe this is a solution: http://www.davidgranado.com/2011/01/serve-a-static-html-file-with-nodejs/ With meteor, you are able to use also npm-packages and nodejs modules like fs!

Comment: but it's not just an HTML file, it has a lot of jquery and javascript in it, some I dont quite understanding. Also the css in it has some badly-defined naming that is okay as a stand-alone project but will cause problems when trying to integrate... Theres no way to simply point to a separate entity but still have that entity share the same root domain name?

the file also has some html  properties of it that I can't straight up port to meteor because meteor automatically does its html tags I think.

Comment: Why would you like meteor for this?

Answer (score 2):

you can connect to another app by using DDP.connect() and it acts like REST API for websockets.

Comment: thanks for sharing! I actually don't need observe the chagne in data in the non-meteor side I think, would I still try to use DDP or would I just use a simple href?